# how to list initialise a templated class without std::initializer_list so it has a fixed size

Tags: c++, templates, arduino, initialization

Without using stdlib(due to arduino platform) I'm trying to create a map like class that I can use to run functions given a string. Its size needs to be fixed on creation. So i've been trying to figure out how to create it using either templates or variadic templates, but i'm not well enough versed to make it work.

ideally it would be created similar to this

```cpp
class parent_class {
    StringMap mymap{
        { "command1", parent_class::member_function },
        { "command2", parent_class::member_function },
        ...
    };
    ...
}
```

but I have struggled to find the correct combination of template and variadic parameters, I did eventually get something working with std::initializer_list but that's not available to me on the arduino platform, so its a non starter.

I don't really care how it works under the hood and i've worked through documentation and examples to find a way to make this happen and it feels like it should be able to be accomplished.

Using this i would then do a binary search over the map, and if no exact match the nearest neighbours to the next best would be shown as suggestions. but i'm stuck at the underlying mechanism. below is the closest i get before getting stuck and re-writing and then getting stuck again.

````cpp
#include <string>

template< typename T >
struct Pair {
    std::string path;
    T object;
};

template< class T >
struct StringMap {
    StringMap( T args[] ){

    }
};

class Parent {
    void testfunc(int data){}
    void testfunc2(int data){}
    StringMap<void (Parent::*)(int)> map{
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"command1", &Parent::testfunc},
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"command2", &Parent::testfunc2}
        };
};

int main(){

    Parent test;

    //Then i could run something like test.run("command1", 1);
    return 0;
}```

Compiler commandline for the arduino studio starts like this:

avr-gcc/5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560
````

Comment: How come you have variadic templates but no initializer_list? They both are C++11 features.

Comment: variadic templates are part of the language, std::initializer_list<T> is part of the standard library. I don't have access to the standard library on Arduino.

Comment: What C++ standard are you working with?

Comment: the arduino studio lists -std=gnu++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to just rely on aggregate initialization of a plain array member:

```
template< class T, int N>
struct StringMap {
    // Do not add a constructor!

    Pair<T> values[N];
};

class Parent {
    void testfunc(int data){}
    void testfunc2(int data){}
    StringMap<void (Parent::*)(int), 2> map{
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"command1", &Parent::testfunc},
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"command2", &Parent::testfunc2}
        };
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sjbE4B

To keep it simple I left the size to be specified manually. There's probably a way to deduce not only the size but also the `T`, but I don't think the code becomes clearer that way.

Also note that if you specify too large an `N`, the remaining array entries will be zero-initialized, you have to get that one right. (But you do get a compile-time error if you use too many initializers).

Comment: thanks max, thats exactly the solution i was working on.

Comment: I thought perhaps i could use a typedef to make it less wierd looking.. hoping someone comes up with some strategies to make it cleaner..

Comment: @Enetheru Just add `using CommandPair = Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>;` or similar into the class and then use `CommandPair` instead of `Pair<...>` in the initialization if that bothers you.

Comment: Thanks a lot max, Marked your's as correct as thanks for helping out.

Comment: It would seem that arduino studio doesnt like to do it without a constructor. complains about "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer", with the constructor it works ok but that requires more massaging.

Comment: @Enetheru Please be more specific about the compiler and the flags used in that case. `-std=gnu++11` compiles the code just fine even with quite old `gcc`: https://godbolt.org/z/eTc6eX That said, I can see 4.9.1 [struggling](https://godbolt.org/z/DaVJbm). Please add the exact compiler and version to the question... (Spoiler alert: Adding an extra pair of curly  braces [fixes the error](https://godbolt.org/z/eehxQf).)

Answer (score 0):

So I went back and reviewed the documenation on uniform initialization a bunch more and came up this this as a starting point, but i would like it to be simplified as much as possible. compiles on godbolt.org, and in the arduino studio.

```cpp
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Pair {
    std::string first;
    T second;
};

template<class T,int size>
struct Map {
    template<class... Ts> //somehow enableif size and parameter pack match
    Map(Ts ...input){
        for( int i = 0; i < sizeof...(input); ++i){
        }
    }

    //Rudimentary linear search
    T find(std::string name){
        for( auto i : list){
            if(! i.first.compare(name) ) return i.second;
        }
    }
    Pair<T> list[size];
};

struct Parent{
    void func1( int num ){}
    void func2( int num ){}
    void func3( int num ){}

    Map<void (Parent::*)(int),3> map{
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"func1",&Parent::func1},
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"func2",&Parent::func2},
        Pair<void (Parent::*)(int)>{"func3",&Parent::func3}
    };

    void call(std::string name){
        auto func = map.find(name);
        (this->*func)( 1 );
    }
};

int main(){
    Parent parent;
    parent.call("func1");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you try something like this:

```
template<class T, bool(*cmp)(int,int)>
class strMap{


};
```